# My car won't shift into second its a 5 speed what can it be?

Tags: nissan, shifting, altima, manual-transmission

I have a 2003 Nissan Altima 2.5s 5-speed with about 183K miles. I think it still has the factory clutch, and the transmission fluid is at the correct level. The other day I tried to shift into second gear, but when I let off the clutch it began to grind and then threw it out of gear. Since that incident, I have been unable to get it into second gear even if I try to hold the gear stick in, or try it with the engine off.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not intimately familiar with the Altima's linkage, but I bet something is worn in the shift linkage not allowing it to go into second gear completely, especially since it happens when the vehicle is off. Since it isn't being allowed to go into second gear completely, when torque is applied through the transmission, it is popped out of gear.

This should be a relatively easy fix for a mechanic. Cost shouldn't be too extravagant if this truly is the issue.

Comment: I'd suspect damage to the synchromesh for 2nd gear if it only happened while running but off...I agree with Paulster2.